# Python cx_Oracle prepared statement with qmark

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to work with cx_Oracle, but it seems to dislike what I know about db-api.

These statement work:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "testdboz" ("id", "sessionid") VALUES (2, 123)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "testdboz" ("id", "sessionid") VALUES (:id, :sid)', 
            {'id':1, 'sid':13})
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "testdboz" ("id", "sessionid") VALUES (:1, :2)', [1123, 123])
```

However, this fails:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "testdboz" ("id", "sessionid") VALUES (?, ?)', [1, 123])
```

The above fails with:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-4e9fe350f968> in <module>()
----> 1 cur.execute('INSERT INTO "testdboz" ("id", "sessionid") VALUES (?, ?)', [1, 123])

DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Is there a way to correct this statement? Does `cx_Oracle` suppprt `qmark`?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I found an answer [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.db.cx-oracle/335)...

> You can't truly choose what paramstyle you would like to use. Oracle
>   only natively supports named and numeric paramstyles and cx_Oracle
>   supports both of those.