# importing data to oracle using python cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, import, document, cx-oracle

Hi I am new to python (programming and stackoverflow).  First let me start by saying a little bit about what I am doing and trying to do.

I am using an internal XML API to pull data from an internal database

I parse/format xml result into a txt document (automated this to occur at a
   set interval)

I want to write or import the contents of this document to an oracle database

How would i go about importing or writing this document into an existing oracle database?  I can't seem to find much in the way of documentation with regards to the cx_Oracle module that i am using to establish a connection with my database.  Could any of you kind folk point me in a direction / resource to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SHORT ANSWER:

```
query = """
insert into TABLE(FIELD1, FIELD2, ...) values (VAL1, VAL2, ...)
"""
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
cur.commit()
```

I **strongly** suggest you to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829828/python-cx-oracle-prepared-statement-with-qmark).

## LONG ANSWER:

This is for Linux, in particular for Red Hat. Only the Python code at the end can be used on every OS. Try to adapt these steps to your OS.

0: Install the packages `libaio` and `python-dev` (or python-devel, check your distro)

1: If you don't have `pip`, install it

2: Install oracle `instantclient-basic` and `instantclient-sdk` (or `instantclient-devel`) from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

3: Launch these commands using `bash`. If you don't have `/etc/profile.d/`, check your distro.

```
echo 'ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64"' | \
sudo tee /etc/profile.d/cx_oracle.sh

pip install cx_Oracle
```

4: Logout and login again

5: Before using cx_Oracle, you have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I recommend you to **NOT** set it globally:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
```

6: Finally, the Python code:

```
import cx_Oracle

os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"
con_str = "USERNAME/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DBNAME"
con = cx_Oracle.connect(con_str)

query = """
select 1 from dual
"""
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row) # it should print "1"

con.close()
```

You have to change the `con_str`  with your username, password etc. The line that sets `utf-8` encoding is optional and adaptable to your needs, but recommended.

7: If you want to insert rows:

```
query = """
insert into TABLE(FIELD1, FIELD2, ...) values (VAL1, VAL2, ...)
"""
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
cur.commit()
```

I **strongly** suggest you to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829828/python-cx-oracle-prepared-statement-with-qmark) if you can't trust the source of the data.

Sources:

1. http://chilipuppy.blogspot.it/2008/10/purpose-im-working-on-building-python.html
2. http://agiletesting.blogspot.it/2005/05/installing-and-using-cxoracle-on-unix.html
3. http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
4. Personal hassle

Comment: Great thanks!  I forgot to mention that i was already able to connect to the DB prior to making my post.

Comment: @shannona2013: can you also provide an example of your txt data?

Comment: sure, let me know if this is what you meant.  i replaced the user name and other things with more general info.  Also i should mention that the source is trustworthy as i made it myself.  is it possible to insert the document into the table directly like i would within toad?



867916136,john,Save,0,server,Web Interface,HTML (UI),15,2015-09-09T12:31:53-04:00

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically "how do I get started with cx_Oracle?"

There's some snippets here:

http://markharrison.net/cx-oracle-demos

and your simplest cx_Oracle program is something like this:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger')
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute('select 2+2 from dual')
print curs.fetchall()

curs.execute('insert into mytable(x) values(3)')
conn.commit()

curs.execute('select * from mytable')
for row in curs:
    print row

conn.close()
```

Comment: thank you so much!  this link is exactly the type of stuff i was looking for :)